# How to give reference lines dicom pic on Dicom pics in CLEARCANVAS?

Tags: visual-studio, open-source, image-processing, dicom, clearcanvas

[image]

i will do that if i open my dicom pics.i have a study . if you look below pic you can see study pic left corner. Big pic is one of series. How can i do that clearCanvas open source sdk?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the code to do this myself, but check out the efforts to implement MPR (multi-planar reconstruction) in ClearCanvas. It does something very similar and may give you the right pointers

Answer (score 0):

[Part 3 of the DICOM 2011 standard](http://medical.nema.org/Dicom/2011/11_03pu.pdf), section C.7.6.2.1.1 (pages 409-11) gives a detailed description of how the geometry of the images is represented in the header.  Use this to get the vertices of both the image of interest and the scout image and the rest is just a matter of doing a bit of linear algebra to compute their intersection in 3-dimensional space.